# dropdown menu not work correctly - bootswatch cosmo

Tags: drop-down-menu

```
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu show" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

In cosmo bootswatch [boostrap theme] js for dropdown menu not work!?
as you see in up image, menu only droped down!
I run it on localhost 
I see other posts on stack but not worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

fixed;
add two script tag in end of layout :

```
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script src="https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://bootswatch.com/_vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```